# How do I search PDFs in Acrobat in Safari using command-f, without an extra buttom press?

Tags: safari, pdf, safari-extensions, adobe

I like using Acrobat within Safari as a convenience. But when I try to search in a PDF with command-F, it first brings up the *Safari* search box, which steals the focus from Acrobat's own search box. This amounts of a lot of annoying extra clicks or button presses to search in PDFs from inside the browser. How can I short-circuit this behavior?

And if there's another in-browser PDF reader that avoids this problem (and is also free and is light/fast/safe), I'd take that as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are oping the PDF files using the Safari PDF reader.

You need the AdobePDFViewer.plugin to replace the Safari build in PDF reader.

Here are the [instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/blocked-plugin-alert-safari-7.html) how to do that.

[image: pdf]

**Update:**

Based on our discussion and your very specific needs here is a proposal.

Reassign the Safari default for "Find" keyboard short cut.

Open sys pref- keyboard - shortcuts.

Click on app shortcut

Select Safari

Type "Find..." (the 3 dots are important)

Select new short cut "<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>"

Now when you use the "cmd -F" only Adobe search will show

When you use the shift- cmd -F the Safari search will show up.

Comment: Just tested, the instructions you posted don't fix the problem (and I also kind of like the default Ask behavior).

Comment: Also, my version of Safari didn't appear to have a built-in reader. When I got my computer, download+Preview was the default behavior. So I installed the Adobe reader plugin.

Comment: So it should work now if you have the Adobe reader installed.

Comment: Except I've had the reader installed this whole time, and no it doesn't work because I just tried it. Cmd-F still brings up both search boxes, and Safari's search box gets the focus by default.

Comment: You could kill Safari' ability to read PDF files all together. defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES

Comment: I explicitly *want* to read PDFs inside my browser.